# Adding CSS to JQuery Validation error messages

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I've been putting together my first Ajax powered form ([here](http://thenally.com/work/ajax-php/)), with the end goal of sending the form data to a MySQL database.  I have minimal experience with PHP and Javascript, and have therefore adopted JQuery Formwizard as my path of choice.  The form works great, however I haven't had much luck finding resources to help me write my 'process.php' script.

The form, by default, currently returns a string such that item1=foo&item2=bar..., which displays on submit.  I have attached the JS below and the gist of my process.php file, but am not sure how the two tie together.  The submit button doesn't seem to be directing to the script at all.  The form is kinda long, but simple, so I've just included some of it.
Thanks a lot,

Mike

**HTML (SNIPPET)**

```
<form action="path/to/process-form.php" method="POST" id="demoForm" class="bbq">

                <div id="fieldWrapper">

                    <span class="step" id="first">

                        <span class="font_normal_07em_black">Manufacturer Information</span><br />

                        <p class="section-desc">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In non est est. Quisque sit amet tellus nulla, 
                        eget molestie velit. Morbi dapibus ornare purus eget ultrices. In et massa ac diam vulputate auctor. 
                        Curabitur ut velit nisi, vel suscipit ligula. Donec non tellus id mauris ornare laoreet sed quis massa. 
                        </p>

                        <br />

                        <div class="clear-line"></div>

                        <br />

                        <label for="manu_name">Manufacturer</label><br />
                        <input class="input_field_12em" name="manu_name" id="manu_name" /><br />

                        <label for="manu_web">Website</label><br />
                        <input class="input_field_12em" name="manu_web" id="manu_web" value="http://" /><br />

                        <label for="manu_email">Email</label><br />
                        <input class="input_field_12em" name="manu_email" id="manu_email" /><br />

                        <label for="manu_phone">Phone</label><br />
                        <input class="input_field_12em" name="manu_phone" id="manu_phone" />
                        <label for="manu_phone_ext">ext</label>
                        <input class="input_field_12em" name="manu_phone_ext" id="manu_phone_ext" /><br />

                        <label for="manu_info">Additional Info</label><br />
                        <textarea class="input_field_12em" name="manu_info" id="manu_info"></textarea><br />

                    </span>
```

**...continued**

```
                <div id="demoNavigation">                           
                    <input class="navigation_button" id="back" value="Back" type="reset" />
                    <input class="navigation_button" id="next" value="Next" type="submit" />
                </div>

</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
                        $("#demoForm").formwizard({ 
                            formPluginEnabled: true,
                            validationEnabled: true,
                            focusFirstInput : true,
                            formOptions :{
                                        type:'POST',
                                success: function(data){$("#status").fadeTo(5000,1,function(){ $(this).html("Product successfully submitted!").fadeTo(5000, 0); })},
                                beforeSubmit: function(data){$("#data").html("data sent to the server: " + $.param(data));},
                                dataType: 'json',
                                resetForm: true
                            },
                            validationOptions : {
                                rules: {

                                <!-- Manufacturer validation -->

                                    manu_name: "required",
                                    manu_email: {
                                        email: true
                                    },

                                },
                                messages: {
                                    required: "This field is required.",
                                    email: "Please enter a valid email address."
                                }
                                }
                            });
                        });
```

**PHP** (process-form.php)

```
<?php

include('dbconnect.php');

/* manufacturer */

$manu_name  = $_POST['manu_name'];
$manu_web   = $_POST['manu_web'];
$manu_email     = $_POST['manu_email'];
$manu_phone     = $_POST['manu_phone'];
$manu_phone_ext = $_POST['manu_phone_ext'];
$manu_info  = $_POST['manu_info'];

$manu_name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($manu_name);
$manu_web   = mysqli_real_escape_string($manu_web);
$manu_email     = mysqli_real_escape_string($manu_email);
$manu_phone     = mysqli_real_escape_string($manu_phone);
$manu_phone_ext = mysqli_real_escape_string($manu_phone_ext);
$manu_info  = mysqli_real_escape_string($manu_info);

$query = "INSERT INTO pd_products
        (manu_name,manu_web,manu_email,manu_phone,manu_phone_ext,manu_info) 
         VALUES ('$manu_name','$manu_web','$manu_email','$manu_phone','$manu_phone_ext','$manu_info')";

if (!mysqli_query($query,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
  }
mysqli_close($con)

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you change "form action="path/to/process-form.php"" in the HTML to the actual path where the form is located.

mysqli_query($query,$con) should be mysqli_query($con,$query) with link, they query. Also, why not just use mysql_query($query,$con)?

Seems like you're using alot of unnecessary code to do something simple.

Place the HTML and PHP in a .php file ( make sure the PHP is in  braces), change the form action to it's own name (to submit to itself), and get rid of the javascript.

Check here for PHP form validation: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @techjunkie.  I simply changed the action path for the post.  By removing the javascript I think i'll lose the ajax functionality that I require for the form, or is that javascript simply for the form submission?  I'll try it out and will post back.

Comment: As I suspected, the javascript above initiates the ajax and provides options for how the form data is handled.  My issue is sending the data-string that is already being output correctly by the plugin and sending it to the database.

Comment: I thought you said the submit button would not submit the form? If the form works, and the information won't send to the database, try replacing the "mysqli_query" functions with "mysql_query" functions. And like I said above I believe you have the "mysqli_query" function backwards which could also be causing the error, check here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php. Also using an error handler may provide insight: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp

Comment: ...thanks a lot, I suspect that you're right. I just tested a simpler form without the formwizard functionality and it sent correctly, I must have a syntax error somewhere in the PHP. Thanks again.